# How can I make an ImageView that doesn't draw the transparent parts of the image?

Tags: android, imageview, alpha, colorfilter

I need my custom ImageView (called `ItemAnimationView`) to not draw any part of its image that is transparent.

I use this class for a lot of instances and for a lot of different images, so it would be best if I could solve this problem only with methods that I can call on `ImageView`, as editing all the different images manually won't work.

So is there some kind of `ColorFilter` that does not only filter out one certain color but instead every pixel that is transparent to any degree?

Also it would be quite convenient if there was a way to do this without accessing the actual bitmap, as the only lines of code I use for the view so far are

```
setImageResource(item.getResourceID());
```

and some animating, so I don't have the associated `Bitmap` object.

Comment: `"I need my custom ImageView (called ItemAnimationView) to not draw any part of its image that is transparent."` - what does "transparent" mean here? (alpha channel != 255)?

Comment: Exactly. I only want to see pixels which have the alpha value `255`.

Comment: try playing with `ColorMatrixColorFilter` - i think you could that but you would need to google a bit about that color matrix (and read `android.graphics.ColorMatrix` official docs)

Comment: 3 minute googling gives: http://www.quasimondo.com/colormatrix/ColorMatrix.as - it has `thresholdAlpha` function - but i have no idea how it works (or even if it is the same matrix)

Comment: I do kind of understand it, but the problem is that that method has an input, and java ColorMatrixFilters only give the opportunity to scale and translate values without any arguments. If I could use the original alpha value as an argument to a custom mathematical function I would know how to solve the problem...

Comment: you mean `thresholdAlpha(threshold:Number, factor:Number = 256)` function? if so, it sets `s` and `t` components used to compute the target alpha: `A’ = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the desired effect using a `ColorMatrixColorFilter` with this matrix:

```
{1f,0f,0f,0f,0f,
0f,1f,0f,0f,0f,
0f,0f,1f,0f,0f,
0f,0f,0f,256f,-256*254};
```

Comment: when i see it now, what about: 0, 0, 0, 256, -256 * 255 ? i mean `factor=256`  and `threshold=255`? (or maybe  threshold=254)?

Comment: indeed - i made a quick test - `0, 0, 0, 256, -256 * 254` is what you need

Comment: thanks, I updated the answer (assuming the `254` was not a typo, or was it meant to be `255`)?

Comment: first i tried 255 but it turned out that every pixel was vanished - if you see how alpha is computed: `A’ = p*R + q*G + r*B + s*A + t` - in your case it is `A’ = 0*R + 0*G + 0*B + 256*A + (-256 * 255)` which is: `A’ = 256 * A - 256 * 255` - so if `A == 255` then `A' == 0` but with 254 it is: `A’ = 256 * A - 256 * 254` and for `A == 255` `A’ == 255` and 0 for any other `A`